# How to include JS file from npm package to separate page in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I have several `npm` packages with client-side scripts I want to include to separate pages of my Nuxt.js project. I have tried to do that with:

```
<script>
export default {
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: "gojs/release/go.js", type: "text/javascript" }
    ]
  },

  // ...
}
</script>
```

but received `404 (Not Found)` error. What is correct way to do that?

Comment: Try including the files as [static assets](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets#static) (e.g., `/assets/static/gojs/release/go.js`), which will make them available at the root (`/`). Then in your `.vue`, the `src` url should be prefixed with `/` (`/gojs/release/go.js`).

Comment: Yes, I know about this way, but I want to include scripts from `node_modules` so when I update packages with npm - they will be updated.

Comment: importing them in plugin with ssr false dont fit?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Normally, importing the module (e.g., with `import go from 'gojs'`) and using it in your code are all you need to do for the build to include that dependency. See [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q9or604w8j?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)-ing the module (e.g., with `import go from 'gojs'`) and using it in your code are all you need to do for the build to include that dependency. No need to add headers to load the NPM module.

Example in `MyFoo.vue`:

```
<script>
import go from 'gojs'

export default {
  mounted() {
    const $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    const myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
        {
          "undoManager.isEnabled": true
        });

    ...
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q9or604w8j?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)